# Android Emulator is showing only black screen, ONLY for API 34

Tags: android, emulation

Android Emulator is showing only black screen when it starts. This is happening only if I choose API level 34. It is working fine for lower level.

[image]

Does anyone know what is the issue and what is the solution?

I am using Android Studio version:

```
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 1
Build #AI-232.8660.185.2321.10696284, built on August 22, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.thoughtworks.gauge (232.8660.142)
```

Comment: What permissions does your app define in the `AndroidManifest.xml`? Are there any logs during app start that might give a hint on what's going on? Maybe post the `Application` class as well as the `MainActiviy.onCreate()` code.

Comment: @muetzenflo it is not related to my app. Just Emulator is not loading Android. It opens but shows only black screen.

Comment: 1) What version of Android Emulator do you have installed according to the SDK Tools tab. 2) If you update to latest, delete and recreate AVDs. 3) Have you tried to launch AVD from the command line with different GPU options: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#command-gpu

Comment: @MorrisonChang that's another issue : https://stackoverflow.com/q/77152438/1397821 
My version is written here

Comment: On MacOS, my colleague had the same problem with Android Studio Flamingo, MacOS Ventura 13.4, running on M2 MacBook, whereas I tried with Android Studio Flamingo, macOS Catalina, running on an x86 MacBook, and the emulator worked fine on mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. It was a bug in older version of Android Emulator.

I was not able to Update the emulator due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77152438/1397821). Then I found a fix for that and Updated the Emulator. Then I removed the Emulator 14.0 and added again.

It is working fine now.

Thanks to @Morrison for giving the clue.

Comment: Thanks, this helped my colleagues too. Just needed an Android Emulator update.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio,

Go to Tools -> SDK Manager ->Android SDK -> SDK Platforms -> Android API 34 -> Install Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image

This worked for me.