# Android Emulator not updating. crashpad_handler.exe

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, updates

My "Android Emulator" in SDK tools is not upgrading

[image]

Whenever I try to update, i get this error during installation:

```
An error occurred during installation: C:\Users\muham\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\crashpad_handler.exe
```

Does anyone know what is this and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix that somehow worked for me:

Before Updating the Emulator, I removed it but Unchecking "Android Emulator" and clicking Apply / OK. After that I tried to Update and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure an emulator is not currently running. If it is running, an uninstallation also won't complete. So, close the emulator and restart the update.